# Using latest libraries for apps on old Android devices

Tags: java, android, version, libraries, legacy

I have updated the Apache Commons Compress to the latest 1.18 in my Android project which has minSdkVersion 16

Everything was fine(build, run) until I have tested it on old Xoom device with Android 4.1

It did not crash but worked wrong and it was really hard to diagnose what's wrong.

I end up with some log records like

> unable to resolve static field (UTF_8) in
>   Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
>
> NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing
>   Lorg/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipEncodingHelper

And find out the problem is lack of support java.nio.charset in the pre 19 Androids.

**QUESTION 1: Is there a way to add support of Java 1.7 and newer on the older devices?** So the all latest libraries which tend to move toward minimum required Java version 1.7 and up will work on such devices with no problem. May be some Google Play settings?

Guess answer for Q1 is NO. So...

**QUESTION 2:  Should we use libraries with minimum JDK 1.6 for Android if we want to run our app on older devices**(e.g., minSdkVersion 16). I managed to resolve my issue migrating back to the latest Commons Compress 1.12 with minimum 1.6 JDK

**QUESTION 3: Is there a way to check whether all dependencies gonna work with old devices without the need to test the app on such devices?** E.g., some tool to validate dependencies against particular Android SDK.